# Template parse warnings event after updating node_modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli, node-modules

When i run my application, i get a warning message in my console stating as below.

I get this error in  `\node_modules\events\events.js`

I've also updated the events modules and current version in package.json is `"events": "^1.1.1"`

Help me to fix this.

```
<template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("
    </div>
  </div>
  [WARNING ->]<template *ngIf="templateCmp" #templateOutlet></template>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show the entire error

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular v4, `template` is deprecated. ng-template was introduced in version 4.0.0-rc1, [see release notes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

change... `<template>` to `<ng-template>`

Comment: this is inside node_modules how do i suppose to change it ?

Comment: @arunkumar, I doubt the issue is in events. Can you show full log of the error?